# How to update the Vertex/Edge ID in Gremlin?

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

How to update the vertex/Edge ID?

```
g.V('jesica@rickandmorty.com').property(T.id, 'jerry@rickandmorty.com')
```

Getting the following error in `Gremlin.version() ==>3.4.10.`

```
{"detailedMessage":"org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.T$2 
    cannot be cast to java.lang.String","requestId":"ade01b34-8eec-46c4-9901-62dc1034f239",
       "code":"UnsupportedOperationException"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` and `label` of a `Vertex` (or `Edge` for that matter) is immutable. If you want to change the `id` you would have to remove the `Vertex` and then add it back. The error message is a bit misleading in older versions of Gremlin. As of 3.4.11 it now reads:

```
gremlin> g.V(1).property(T.id, 200).iterate();
T.id is immutable on existing elements
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]y
java.lang.IllegalStateException: T.id is immutable on existing elements
```

Comment: Thanks @stephen mallette

Comment: I am using `gremlin> Gremlin.version() ==>3.5.0`. But that's ok. I got the answer.

Comment: that's odd - i tested on 3.4.11 and 3.5.0 and get the same message. i noticed that you posted a JSON style error message indicative of Gremlin Server usage - perhaps you have a server on an older version that is producing that error?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I am using AWS Neptune `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/engine-releases-1.0.4.2.R2.html`. It's `TinkerPop 3.4.10`